# How to get snapshot of current time in VBA?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

In my VBA code, I am updating cells with either `Cell.Value = Now` or `Cell.Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")`.

I am doing this for four different cells. However, I notice that when one of the cells change, the rest of the timestamps change to reflect the current time. To me it seems that these cells are just a reference to the latest time, and not a snapshot of when the cell was updated.

Is there anyway to take a snapshot of the time so that it won't change on a sheet refresh?

Comment: What you're seeing isn't consistent with how you're setting the cells' values, so something else is going on. Setting to `Now` should insert a fixed value.  What's the context in which you're setting the values - how is it triggered?

Comment: Is your VBA code included in a worksheet_change or a worksheet_selectionchange macro? In that case your cells are fixed, but they get updated every time something else changes in the sheet.

Comment: Through some reuters API, I had four different callback methods. I pretty much wanted to timestamp when those methods got called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those cells are just a "reference" to the latest time, better still it's possible they would be different times.

Save the time into a variable at some suitable point in your code, then use that value in the cells. Then you can control which Now you actually mean.